# implement multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

how to to implement multithreading where 
one thread updating UI
and other one is reading the database record
in windows application

Any guidelines really appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

you should look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

This will allow you to start the database operations on a background thread, so that your UI is not locked and also to report progress back to the main thread so you can update the UI with the results.

Comment: yeah it was.  yours was slightly more compact, so +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

You already have your UI thread running. Hence create a thread/[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the db operation.

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundworker has some convenient functions to do work without blocking the UI while it's possible to update the UI. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)